# Get the record with the most recent date. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 715 | 2022-03-20 | 183.74 |
| 715 | 2022-03-13 | 86.45 |
| 715 | 2022-03-06 | -10.84 |
| 715 | 2022-02-27 | 291.87 |
| 715 | 2022-02-20 | 194.58 |
| 715 | 2022-02-13 | 97.29 |
| 715 | 2022-02-06 | 0.00 |

Is there a way to get the ID,and value for the last day of each month provided.

Output

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 715: | :2022-03-20: | 183.74: |
| 715: | :2022-02-27: | 291.87: |

Thanks, I have already tried

```
SELECT T.*
FROM (
  SELECT ID, value, date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date ASC) AS rn
  FROM table
) t
```

But doesn't quite do it.

Thanks

Comment: Please make your problem more clear than "But doesn't quite do it." ...

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn`

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @arsenaql: I edited the first table (for aligning data), I left it as an exercise for you  to do the same with the second table. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust your current query to sort `row_number` descending and add a partition on the month of your date. Then, add a where clause to pull `rn = 1`:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM (
  SELECT ID, value, date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, month(Date) ORDER BY Date desc) AS rn
  FROM table
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

If you need to expand this to multiple years, you can inlcude a partition on the year as well:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM (
  SELECT ID, value, date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, month(Date), year(Date) ORDER BY Date desc) AS rn
  FROM table
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, if I do this the output is only 1 row where I need a row for each month

Answer (score -3):

SELECT T.*
FROM (
SELECT ID, value, date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, month(Date) ORDER BY Date desc) AS rn
FROM table
) t
where t.rn = 1

Comment: The request is several months old, so I suppose that the OP has just forgotten to mark Sadly Full Stack's answer as accepted. Your answer is an exact copy of Sadly Full Stack's first query. Why are re-posting this?

Comment: A copy of a previous answer